# problemas con el operador spread

Tags: javascript, array, funciones

Segun tenia entendido que al usar el operador Spread (...) copiaba los elementos de  array y si lo ponia en otra variable (nuevoArray) creaba un array diferente vinculado al array primero(array) es decir que de ahi en adelante podia modificar nuevoArray y no afectaria a array pero si modificaba array si modificaba nuevoArray... pero veo que no es asi alguien me puede explicar porque y cual seria el mejor modo de copiar los elementos de un parametro en una nueva variable que no afecte los datos del parametro original??

```
function modificar (array){
    let nuevoArray =[...array]
    console.log(array)
    console.log(nuevoArray)
    nuevoArray[0][1]='esto afecta a los dos arrays'
    console.log(array)
    console.log(nuevoArray)
}
modificar([['a','b'],['c','d']])
```

Comment: Ojo, eso de copiar con el spread solo funciona para array simples, no para arrays que contienen objetos u otros arrays. Un truco para copiar sin problemas es `let nuevoArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Para los objetos anidados, el operador spread proporcionará una
> copia completa de la primera instancia de los valores, pero deja todos
> los datos anidados como copias superficiales que comparten un espacio
> en la memoria con el original.
> Entonces:

Debemos cambiar la referencia interna en nuevoArray[0] a una nueva matriz
la cual la crearemos aplicando nuevamente al operador de propagación
`nuevoArray[0]=[...array[0]]`

```js
function modificar (array){
    
    let nuevoArray =[...array];
    
    nuevoArray[0]=[...array[0]];
  
 nuevoArray[0][1]='esto ahora no afectara a los dos arrays'
    
   
    console.log('original no se  modifica:',array)
    console.log(nuevoArray)
}
modificar([['a','b'],['c','d']])
```

Esto es porque:

La sintaxis spread  llega hasta  a un nivel de profundidad cuando copias un arreglo multidimensional
Por lo cual no te permite modificar a tu array multidimensional `nuevoArray` de forma tal que
`nuevoArray` no modifique al original en el nivel que pretendes hacerlo para poder hacerlo hay que aplicar nuevamente al operador spread
Porque estas accediendo internamente al nuevoArray a un nivel
de profundidad en el cual el primer spread no llega pues al modificar  b esa modificación
se vera reflejada en el original

> Podes ver al nivel que llega por ejemplo

`nuevoArray.push('Hola array desde nuevo:');`
`original : [ [ 'a', 'b' ], [ 'c', 'd' ] ]`

> no modificara a tu array original por el nivel que afecta push()
> Pero !!:

`nuevoArray[0][1].push('Hola  array desde nuevo :');`

> Si lo modificara porque apuntara al mismo índice de la matriz dada la
> profundidad

`//original luego de push() profundo:[ [ 'a', 'b', 'Hola  array desde nuevo :' ], [ 'c', 'd' ] ]`

> Lo mismo vale si usaras Object.assign()porque solo copiaran la
> referencia del objeto interno y lo podrán modificar. El operador spread
> hace copias profundas si los datos no están anidados porque creara una
> copia superficial de los datos anidados copiara la misma referencia
> Si quieres cambiar la referencia para si poder hacer una copia profunda
> aplicar nuevamente  spread en el nivel que sea posible

`nuevoArray[0]=[...array[0]]`

```js
function modificar (array){
    
    let nuevoArray =[...array]
    nuevoArray[0]=[...array[0]]
    
    
    nuevoArray[0].push('Hola  array nuevamente :');
    console.log('modifica copia internamente:',nuevoArray)
    
    console.log('original no se modifica!!: ',array)
}
modificar([['a','b'],['c','d']])
```

> Hay librerias y otros metodos cada uno puede ser mejor de acuerdo al
> caso en tu caso prefiero al spread operator
> porque aunque requerimos menos codigo con :

```
    function modificar (original){
    let nuevo=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(original))
    
    nuevo[0][1]='hola'
    console.log(nuevo);
    console.log(original)
    }
    modificar([['a','b'],['c','d']])

/* [ [ 'a', 'hola' ], [ 'c', 'd' ] ] [ [ 'a', 'b' ], [ 'c', 'd' ] ]



*/
```

> con spread veo un mayor control.Y pueden ocurrir problemas al usar JSON.stringify ya que no es recomendado para algunos tipos de datos :
> Por ejemplo convertir fechas en string sin quererlo

```
let obj = {
    d: new Date(),
};
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)));
// {d: "2020-08-12T04:47:40.958Z"}
```

y otros inconvenientes [desventajas de JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))](https://developpaper.com/why-not-recommended-json-stringify-make-a-deep-copy/)

```
const arrOfFunction = [
  () => 2,
  {
    test: () => 3,
  },
  Symbol('4'),
];
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arrOfFunction)));
/*[ null, {}, null ]
JSON remplazara function con null y function en objeto con undefined*/
```

Con spread:

```js
const arrOfFunction = [
  () => 2,
  {
    test: () => 3,
  },
  Symbol('4'),
];
let nuevo = [...arrOfFunction]
console.log(nuevo[0]())
//2
```

> spread operator tiene muchísima utilidad rápidamente nos permite
> crear objetos que tengan propiedades propias y comunes con el original
> sin modificar al original

```js
const arryOf = [
  [{
    id: '4'
  }],
  {
    sala: 'principal',
  }

];
let nuevo = [...arryOf];
// creamos una nueva referencia para el array interno
// le agregamos un objeto al array interno 
nuevo[0] = [...arryOf[0], {
  hola: 'que tal'
}]

console.log(nuevo);
//[ [ { id: '4' }, { hola: 'que tal' } ], { sala: 'principal' } ]
console.log('No se modifica original', arryOf)
//no se modifico [ [ { id: '4' } ], { sala: 'principal' } ]
```

> Entonces Para tipos de datos no primitivos, es necesario aplicar el
> operador de propagación para  cada nivel de anidamiento para clonar en
> profundidad el objeto para no mutarlo. Tambien podremos usarlo para
> clonar las propiedades enumerables de un objeto

```js
const objetoOriginal = {
  nombre: 'Original',
  conoce: ['Typescript', 'Angular', 'Angular Material'],
};
const copiaProfunda = {
  ...objetoOriginal,
  conoce: [...objetoOriginal.conoce]
};
copiaProfunda.conoce.push('#C');
// La referencia del array Anidado es distinta
console.log(objetoOriginal.conoce === copiaProfunda.conoce);
console.log('array anidado original', objetoOriginal.conoce);
console.log('array anidado copia Profunda', copiaProfunda.conoce);
```

> Tenes alguna dificultad adicional por la cual mi respuesta no te es de
> utilidad?